# Origin of a story about a computer in the 50's recommending offing Pensioners

Tags: history

There's a story I've heard a few times in various computer science talks, usually offered as a cautionary tale, that goes something like this:

> In the late 50s, the British gov't purchased an early computer, and tried to build a computer model of the gov'ts budget, including every variable and factor they could think of.  They then had it run an analysis to find the best ways to save money.  The surprising result was they should decrease spending on traffic lights and cross-walks.
>
> This confused the researchers, since these items were a very small fraction of the total budget, much less then what the computer claimed could be saved by eliminating them.  Upon further examination, they found that the source of the savings wouldn't be due to the direct cost of traffic lights, but were due to the increase in pensioners being killed trying to cross the street, thus saving the gov't X millons of dollars.

Even if the story is apocraphyl (which I sort of assume is the case) does anyone know what the original source is?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic. Sure, you might have heard computer scientists telling this tale, but I don't see what this or the truth of it has to do with computer _science_ as such. The tag description 'history' doesn't really seem to fit either (this is not about the history of CS as an academic discipline, this may be an application, but the relation seems rather weak. Replace the computer with a brilliant accountant, the only difference in the story is a slightly more pessimistic outlook on accountants) . Perhaps this is more suitable for [skeptics.se]?

Comment: @Discretelizard Completely off-topic at Skeptics. The question is about the source of the statement, not whether or not it's true. However, it's not a CS question, either. I doubt it's on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Surely apocryphal. I can't imagine anyone in the 1950s having an economic model so detailed that it could come to this conclusion.

Comment: This is certainly not topical in this silo, but it might well be on-topic at [history.se].

Answer (score 1):

The story is clearly made up.

There was no AI in the 1950's that could have come up with that.

There is no AI today and for many years that could come up with that.

Actually, an AI wouldn't come up with this idea at all. You would need a very well calibrated combination of AI and AS (Artificial Stupidity) to achieve this result.

Comment: Eh, its not really something the computer needs to have "come up with".  Somewhere in the giant system of coupled equations that made up the  model someone just needs to have inputted the cost per pensioner and in another place, the effect of traffic control devices on mortality. That kind of thing actually seems to have been pretty popular in the late 50's and 60's.  Here's an example from the Rand Corp circa 1964, for example: https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_memoranda/RM4035.html

Comment: Here's another example from 1968 that actually is (very vaguely) similar to the anecdote: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7906964-the-fires